# show empty dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to return a html by ajax, I have this

```
$("a[rel^='valora']").click(function(){
    var usuario= $(this).data('usuario');
    var idea= $(this).data('idea');
    $("#valorar").load(
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{path('valorarIdea')}}',
                data: {user: usuario, idea: idea},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html'
            })
    ).dialog()
});
```

I have a this template a div to open de dialog

```
<div id="valorar" title="Valorar  una idea">

</div>
```

this open de dialog but don´t showme any inside, 
my html is a template html.twig with a form like this...

```
<form action="{{ path('valorarIdea') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

if i change this by other thing like this

```
<p> hello! </p>
```

don´t work too.

Am I missing something?

thanks.

Comment: $("#valorar").load()? do u have any element with id 'valorar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You place ajax call in load call. That is wrong. Take look at this : http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
.load(url, data, callbackfunction)
```

**EDIT** : Example in your case :

```
$("#valorar").load( '{{path('valorarIdea')}}', data: {user: usuario, idea: idea}).dialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `$('<div id="valorar"></div>').load().dialog();`